# Is there a Google Sheets function that can give a "Yes" or "No" answer, depending on a cell value?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say we have Jeff and Susie. Jeff has $700, Susie has $430. They want to buy an iPhone. Is there a function on the same sheet that can say "Yes" if he has over $700 and "No" if he has under $700?

I'd also want it to be a function in a cell, not conditional formatting: [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18VkV.png)

Comment: =IF(A1>=700,"Yes","No")

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(B2>700,"Yes","No")` will return `Yes` if the value in the cell `B2` is over 700, and `No` if it's less than 700.

[image: An image of the formula working.]